# I'm not able to stop all the services in tableau. All the processes are in error state. Is there a force mode to stope the processes?

Tags: tableau-api

I was planning to do an upgrade. I'm not able to stop all the services in tableau. All the processes are in error state

I stopped the TS
I ran the stop-administrative-services
I ran the tableau obliterate cmd

For some reason the application did not get uninstalled. So -

I started administrative services
I started the TS. Everything is fine
I tried to stop the TS but all the process are in error state
I also did a system restart and repeated the steps but it didn't work

Is there a way to force stop all the process ?